# Чи потрібна кома після "тобто"?

Tags: пунктуація

Дивлюсь у [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/tobto) і бачу:

Без коми після "тобто":

> - Чернишеві на час артпідготовки випало бути старшим, тобто командувати з'єднаним вогнем усіх трьох мінрот
> - Ми зустрілися з ним на березі Азовського моря — поблизу Матроської слобідки під Маріуполем, тобто нинішнім містом Жданов
> - Тобто вичавлювання виробів з металу, який під дією високого тиску стає м'яким

З комою після "тобто":

> - Наказую… Тобто, щиро прошу всіх присутніх з'їсти по пів-яблука номер один і при цьому дивитись на мене...
> - Тобто, як відвезти?

Comment: ІМХО: в загальному випадку *тобто* - це сполучник, після якого не потрібно коми. Проте, якщо потрібно передати якесь здивування (чи просто така інтонація), то кому можна поставити. Крім того, СУМ каже, що *тобто* може бути і сполучником, і часткою. А ще я б забрав кому з першого прикладу з комою.

Comment: @обставинниковийТранспозитор, див. моє виправлення в цитаті.

Comment: @Sasha для мене нічого не змінилося.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Слово *тобто* (*себто*, *цебто*) є пояснювальним *сполучником*, про що вже казалось у вашому джерелі, тому тільки перед словом ставиться кома або нічого, якщо стоїть на початку речення.

В інших випадках слово є цілим виразом, що виражає деякі смислові функції.

- В першому випадку це скорочення від *тобто [не наказую]*. Це такий ж самий пояснювальний сполучник. Аби це все не промовляти, кажуть тільки *тобто*, але якщо є бажання — можете так робити.
- У другому, залежно від інтонації: *здивування* — *що?* *як?*; *вимагання відповіді* — *що маєш на увазі?*, *це ти про що?*. Тут з'єднали два питання *Тобто? Як відвезти?*.

Деякі джерела [стверджують](http://shkolyar.in.ua/vstavni-slova), що *тобто* не може бути *вставним словом*. В цьому є логіка, бо ви можете без проблем додати потрібні слова до нього без втрати сенсу.